# Keras tensorboard update_freq is flushing rate or accumulating rate?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorboard

I'm using keras callbacks to write logs to tensorboard.
The TensorBoard callback receives `update_freq` param, and according to the docs:

> 'batch' or 'epoch' or integer. When using 'batch', writes the losses
>   and metrics to TensorBoard after each batch. The same applies for
>   'epoch'. If using an integer, let's say 1000, the callback will write
>   the metrics and losses to TensorBoard every 1000 batches. Note that
>   writing too frequently to TensorBoard can slow down your training.

From the docs I understand that tensorboard accumulates logs often and just writes (flush) them to filesystem every `update_freq`.
However when I view scalars for one epoch, I see only *one point* (despite having thousands of steps).

So, which is the correct behaviour here?
Does keras collect every step scalars and just writes to filesystem every `update_freq`, or it also accumulates the scalars every `update_freq` (thus explaining why I see one scalar for a thousand steps epoch)?

Answer (score 0):

By running several tests I can confirm it collects scalars every `update_freq`, so for setting it for `epoch` it will collect metrics just every epoch.